# complex animated objects in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine, sprite

I'd like to implement complex animated weapon objects that have different states and various amount of sprites.

For example one weapon object has 36 sprites for full rotation by 360 degree in isometric projection, also it has 72 additional sprites for shot(2 sprites for each position from previous 36 sprites) and so on.

Some other weapon object will also have 36 sprites for full rotation by 360 degree and have 5(not 2 as a previous one) sprites for each position from previous 36 sprites.

My question is - should I manage animated sprite indexes manualy or some clever tools exists for angengine for similar tasks ?

How best to do it?

Comment: Why do you need so many sprites? You can rotate one sprite :)

Comment: Because object has been rendered in isometric projection. We can use one sprite rotation only in orthographic projection

Comment: For similar kind of game I have used animated sprite in which I have added 36 tile for normal movement and 36 tile for fire movement. Normal movement tiles reside at odd position and all fire movement tiles reside at even position.